# Accessing array beyond it's size

Tags: c, memory

I have this code snippet and I have no idea why it's working in my code.

```
mft_fragment *pfrag = malloc(sizeof(mft_fragment));
printf("size2:%lu\n", sizeof(mft_fragment));
pfrag[23].fragment_count = 10;
```

`printf` prints 8 bytes. Shouldn't I be getting segmentation fault or something like that?

Comment: No.  If code breaks the rules, anything may happen.  C does not require a net.  If code [falls off the tightrope](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2012/06/14/article-2159007-059F0F4D000005DC-442_634x494.jpg), you may get hurt

Comment: *Shouldn't I be getting segmentation fault or something like that?* Not necessarily, that's undefined behaviour, anything goes, it might crash with segfault, you might even start world war 3 :)

Comment: C has no built-in bounds checking. That is up to you as a developer to take care of. This is simply *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Also `"%ld"` is not necessarily the matching f specifier for the result of `sizeof(mft_fragment)`.  Use `"%zu"`

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen An implementation _may_ have built-in bounds checking.  It is all UB.

Comment: ah, thanks guys, found the mistake

Comment: @chux: Yes, but the C standard (C99 or whatever) has no built-in bounds checking. As the question is tagged only as `C` and not to a specific implementation the standards are all we can compare with.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen I think you misunderstood the standard, UB mean implementation is free to do whatever it wants, that include do bound checking and delete all files of your system and more ;)